# Does a target need to be within 5 feet for a Kraken to swallow it?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, attack, grapple

The [Kraken](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Kraken#content) has a bite attack which has the following rules:

> **Bite**: Melee Weapon Attack: +17 to hit, reach 5 ft., one target. Hit: 23 (3d8 + 10) piercing damage. If the target is a Large or smaller creature Grappled by the kraken, that creature is swallowed, and the grapple ends. While swallowed, the creature is Blinded and Restrained, it has total cover against attacks and other Effects outside the kraken, and it takes 42 (12d6) acid damage at the start of each of the kraken's turns. If the kraken takes 50 damage or more on a single turn from a creature inside it, the kraken must succeed on a DC 25 Constitution saving throw at the end of that turn or regurgitate all swallowed creatures, which fall prone in a space within 10 feet of the kraken. If the kraken dies, a swallowed creature is no longer Restrained by it and can escape from the corpse using 15 feet of Movement, exiting prone.

The grapple being mentioned comes from its tentacle attack:

> **Tentacle**: Melee Weapon Attack: +17 to hit, reach 30 ft., one target. Hit: 20 (3d6 + 10) bludgeoning damage, and the target is Grappled (escape DC 18). Until this grapple ends, the target is Restrained. The kraken has ten tentacles, each of which can grapple one target.

The tentacle attack has a range of 30 feet though while the bite has a range of 5 feet. I don't know of any rules saying a creature with a reach attack that can grapple a target can also drag it closer. Does that mean the Kraken can only attempt to use its Bite attack if the target happens to have been grappled while it is only 5 feet away?

Answer (score 8):

### Yes

If the kraken wants to bite a creature grappled by its tentacle then eithier it needs to move its mouth to the creature, which it can do through moving, or move the creature to its mouth, which it can also do through moving as [follows](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Combat#toc_42):

> **Moving a Grappled Creature:** When you move, you can drag or carry the Grappled creature with you, but your speed is halved, unless the creature is two or more sizes smaller than you.

Comment: Thing is, the text says you can drag or carry the grappled creature with you. To me that says you move and it moves. It doesn't say you can drag the creature towards you.